# Initializer requires a body?

Tags: swift, initialization

When I implement the following initializer:

```
init(sourceType: Module, sourceNode: String, trafficSource: String) {

    super.init(sourceType: sourceType, sourceNode: sourceNode, trafficSource: trafficSource)
}
```

I am getting an error: [image]

What is the fix?

Answer (score -1):

Calling `init` on the `super`, does not count as a statement within the body of code.

```
super.init(sourceType: sourceType, sourceNode: sourceNode, trafficSource: trafficSource)
```

You need to add another line of code between the curly braces.